# Reference to assumptions

Tags: cross-referencing, theorems

**Assumption 1.** *(i) something1, (ii) something2*.

I would like to refer to separate parts as 1(i) and 1(ii). Is there any way of doing it? I guess that I can use enumerate and three labels, namely, label1 for assumption1, label2 for (i) and label3 for (iii). But, in that case I would have \ref{label1}\ref{label2}. However, these are two separate objects. Is there any way to make it one object?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{asu}{Assumption}

\begin{document}

\begin{asu} \label{asu1}
    (i) something1, (ii) something2
\end{asu}

Now I refer to it manually, i.e. assumption \ref{asu1}(i). However, this is not the way to go.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below I've defined a new counter that resets with every assumption. Additionally `\subasu` is used in an `\item`-like fashion to print an assumption number, which can be `\label`-ed and `\ref`-erenced:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{asu}{Assumption}
\newcounter{subassumption}[asu]
\renewcommand{\thesubassumption}{(\textit{\roman{subassumption}})}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subassumption}{\theasu}% Counter prefix.
\makeatother
\newcommand{\subasu}{% Just like \item in a list, but for an asu
  \refstepcounter{subassumption}%
  \thesubassumption~\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\begin{asu}\label{asu1}
  \subasu \label{asu1i} something1, \subasu \label{asu1ii} something2
\end{asu}

Now I refer to it autmoatically, i.e. assumption~\ref{asu1ii} or~\ref{asu2i}.

\begin{asu}\label{asu2}
  \subasu \label{asu2i} something1, \subasu \label{asu2ii} something2
\end{asu}

\end{document}
```